# Calling runas from Powershell with forms

Tags: wpf, powershell

I have a series of AD domains, each domain having it's own admin accounts.
I would like to be able to open ADUC from within PowerShell for each domain using the correct credentials.
Because of domain trust setup I can't use the -credential switch when starting a new PS instance so runas /netonly seems to be the best option.

Now this works fine in Powershell - until a GUI front end is added using WPF - the reason being I suspect that PS is trying to use the existing window to display the user/pass prompt but can't because it's tied to a window.

For some reason I can't get it to spawn a new window, even by using start-process. (The start process command below worked fine under PS2 but since upgrading to PS4 it now fails telling me that -STA and -Command aren't real parameters)

I'm using the xaml converter from http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2014/08/01/i-39-ve-got-a-powershell-secret-adding-a-gui-to-scripts.aspx to load a xaml form:

```
<Window 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="UAT" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Grid>
        <Button Name="btnGo" Content="Go" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Margin="207,240,0,0"/>
        <TextBox Name="txtOut" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="233" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="272" Margin="10,0,0,0"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The .PS1 file

```
$c = "admin-" + [Environment]::UserName
$server = "foo.bar"

.\loadDialog.ps1 -XamlPath '.\UAT.xaml'

$btnGo.add_Click({
#Start-Process PowerShell -STA -Command {runas /netonly /user:DOMAIN\$c "mmc.exe dsa.msc /server=$server"}
& runas /netonly /user:DOMAIN\$c "mmc.exe dsa.msc /server=$server"
})

$xamGUI.ShowDialog() | out-null 2>> Errors.txt
```

Is there another way to start this process in such a way that it will spawn it's own window?